# Calculating original signal from Discerete Fourier Transform

Tags: signal-processing, fft, dft

I am trying to calculate the original equation using a dft.

DFT on `(1,0,0,0)` gives `(1,1,1,1)`

So what is the equation of wave representing the dataset (1,0,0,0)? I mean something as follows.

```
f(t)=sin(t)+0.13sin(3t)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is about DSP theory, not programming, and belongs on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

DFT of an impulse is just a flat spectrum in the frequency domain, so you have amplitude 1 at each frequency bin:

```
f(t) = 1 + cos(2πt/4) + cos(4πt/4) + cos(6πt/4)

     = 1 + cos(πt/2) + cos(πt) + cos(3πt/2)
```

Comment: Hi Paul,  thx for reply. I have posted a follow on question at following [link] (http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27406/calculating-original-signal-from-discerete-fourier-transform)  http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27406/calculating-original-signal-from-discerete-fourier-transform